# CSS Hover jitter issue

Tags: html, css

This is my first question. I usually try to research these things well, but this one is driving me crazy.

I need to be able to do something very similar to what you see here (hover over the box):
http://dev.ranvel.com/test-hover-method.html

The problem is the jitter that I get. It looks very unprofessional.

I want to use CSS and HTML (and not images) because what will eventually happen is there will be words behind the box and by hovering, you will see a translation.

What I've seen already are things like keeping the fonts the same, removing bold text, etc. Here, the whole div is changing and not just the text. I've also seen the "transition trick" where you increase the amount of time between the transitions. The problem is that sometimes when the mouse comes to a rest over the div, it is in its "non-hover" state.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please post sample code. If you want to create a working demo, consider using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: You hide your element on mouseOver, so it is not 'overed' anymore. Then its comes back visible. You are doing it the wrong way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of visibility: hidden; try using opacity: 0;

```
.over:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6WPHk/

You can even setup a transition on the `.over` div:

```
.over {
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: This opacity is the missing link that I wasn't able to come up with because I didn't take a break from it. Thanks soo much! This is a really great fix. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to make the `.over` a child of `.under`.

1. It would be a lot easier to position `.over`.
2. You can then apply the hover selector to `.under`, while still applying
   the visibility rule to `.over`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83nAN/1/)

#### HTML

```
<div class="main">la la 
    <div class="under">
        <img class="over" src="//lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="">
        Bibendum Etiam Fermentum Mattis
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.under {
    position: relative;
}

.under:hover .over {
    display: none;
}

.over {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: Your idea about the parent/child relationship as well as the execution was great. This is perfect! Thank so much!